# Convert multiple json items into a array

Tags: arrays, json, jq

From a jq filter from which i get output like below

```
{"name": "xyz", "age": 12}
{"name": "123", "age": 19}
```

But I would like to transform like below

```
{"val" : [
          {"name": "xyz", "age": 12},
          {"name": "123", "age": 19}
         ]
}
```

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

If your input file consists of a stream of objects, use `inputs` in combination with the `--null-input` (or `-n`) flag:

```bash
jq -n '{val: [inputs]}'
```

```json
{
  "val": [
    {
      "name": "xyz",
      "age": 12
    },
    {
      "name": "123",
      "age": 19
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/kmX1PrpB67o)

But if you have a previous filter that produces a stream, you need to tweak that to produce an array instead (often it suffices to wrap all the previous filter in square brackets, but if you generally need help with that as well you should provide it in the question).

Comment: Thanks. I can not use inputs, I have existing jq filter I need to add another filter using PIPE to transform.

Demo Link: https://jqplay.org/s/LxIMkhJyqar

.accounts[] -> I should transform after iterating accounts

Comment: @Madhuprathap You can either pipe two jq calls on the shell (`jq '<your previous filter>' | jq -n '{val: [inputs]}'`), or pipe your filters within one jq call (maybe `jq '[<your previous filter>] | {val: .}'`, maybe not, please provide the previous filter).

Comment: I have tried but I did not work as wanted.

Demo URL: https://jqplay.org/s/LxIMkhJyqar

Comment: @Madhuprathap Given your modified input data from the demo (which should be part of the question): if you didn't use `.[]` to deconstruct the array, it would stay intact and you could just use `{val: .accounts}`. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/X08aFMIsXVe)

Comment: correct. It is part of bigger jq. At the terminal it get printed individual elements. So I have I have to again gather all the elements into a array

Answer (score 0):

As @pmf pointed out in a comment, simply change your existing filter from: `.accounts[]` to

```
{val: .accounts}
```